# My rabbitmq's qps is only 80 in piki 1000 in rabbitmq-c, what's wrong with it?

Tags: python, c, rabbitmq

I have installed rabbitmq, use pika in python and rabbitmq-c in C for testing.

I have done nothing to rabbitmq except that i modify the listener port to my own one.

The producer works the whole night to put enough messages into rabbitmq, about 1000K durable messages.

The customer is written both in C and python, but its qps is just 80 per queue.

The articles on internet says that their single queue can reach 15000 qps, so what's wrong with mine? *Do i need to configure some essential things about rabbitmq?*

Each message is about 100 Btyes long, I use consume ack, and the queue and message are both durable.

Comment: To clarify, you ask for one message, process it, then ask for the next message?

Comment: If you have a 6 ms ping time to the rabbitmq server it is 6 ms to the server, 6 ms back to you. 12.5 ms delay would result in 80 per second. To get 15,000 you'd need to be reading messages non-stop, probably dumping them into a thread pool for processing.

Answer (score 0):

To get a good throughput one should monitor:

1. flow control : memory based, ensure alert levels are set correctly to avoid connections blocking. Connection based ,check publisher and consumer rates are appropriate to avoid flow control)
2. Setting appropriate Qos values for consumers.